# Is it possible to automatically generate PHP function names from an array of values?

Tags: php, arrays, function, auto-generate

I was recently taught the arrays system to shorten my code on Javascript.

```
        var fields = ['username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'type', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'bdate_month', 'bdate_day', 'bdate_year', 'email', 'country', 'state', 'city', 'payment_email'];
        var length = fields.length;
        for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if ($('#' + fields[i]).val() == "") {
        $('#' + fields[i] + '_error').show();
        $('#' + fields[i] + '_error').fadeOut(4000, function() {});
        $('#' + fields[i]).focus();
        return false;
        }
        }
```

This is the code I generated to create a series of conditionals that would validate the contents of a submit form.

Now I would like to use this same principle in PHP to generate a series of functions that will query the logged in user's data from a MySQL database.

I am a newbbie with PHP and I'm aware that the following code might be just a bunch of nonsense gibberish. But maybe you can get an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish here.

```
include("connect.php");

$fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'type', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'bdate_month', 'bdate_day', 'bdate_year', 'email', 'country', 'state', 'city', 'payment_email');
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

for ($i=0; $i<15; $i++) {
function $fields($i)() {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $resultado=mysql_query("$sql");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
    if($row!=NULL)
    {
        echo ($row['$fields($i)']);
    } else {

        echo (" No ".$fields($i)." inserted!");
    }
}
}
```

===========================================
EDIT:

I figured out a much easier and simpler way.

```
function in_user($key) { 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; 
$resultado=mysql_query("$sql"); 
$row=mysql_fetch_array($resultado); 
if($row!=NULL){ 
echo ($row[$key]); 
} else { 
echo ("No {$key}!"); 
} 
}
```

Since all I need to be changing is the field to consult, I think an argumented function would be a lot easier and simpler.

`<?php in_user('email');?>` would output `stored.email@database.com`

Comment: as a note, php has [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) which you might find simpler ==> `foreach($fields as $one_field) { ... }`

Comment: `script.php?username=';drop+table+users --` http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Byron: nice try, but `mysql_query` doesn't support multiple queries. (yes, it's still a major security hole)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you cannot create a function whose name is based on a variable.

Also, in this example you wouldn't gain much, I think it's a lot clearer to use:

```
function user_get_field($fieldname)
```

Now if you need multiple fields this would result in executing multiple queries so it's probably better to retrieve everything and cache it.

Hey, you could even store everything related to the user in the session and update it when he changes his own settings. That's only one query per session.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was guessing it's not possible to create function names based on variables. But as for your last comment... How would I store all the details on the user session? And would that make the navigation slower? or does it even affect it? (Imagine a system with thousands of users online at the same time. Would that be feacible? )

Comment: yes, that's fine. each user has his own settings in his own session. if you often use that data (probably you do) it's definitely faster than retrieving it each time from SQL. If you also store the session in a DB then it's not worth it.

Comment: Actually, you can use variables to trigger functions if those functions are anonymous. Example ==> http://codepad.viper-7.com/3KkN4Y - also see: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Well, at the end, I created a javascript script that till write the functions in plain text. Then copy/pase them on my functions file. Haha.

Comment: @Peter: No, that's a *different thing*. That's a variable storing a function. You can execute functions whose name is stored in a variable, you don't even need anonymous functions for that.

Comment: @Alfie: I really hope that was a joke :P

Comment: @yi_H - Conceptually it's different, but typographically it's what the OP is looking for. So you could have `$firstname();` which is a variable that was created using `$$fieldname = function() ....`. ---------- I agree that using arguments is better.

Comment: since those are *variables* they won't be visible in function scope, so you have to pollute the global namespace.. that's just plain bad. Also totally useless. The whole point of having separate functions for each field doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @yi_H Hahaha. It was not! I know it sounds quite silly, but it's just me testing different solutions. I'm still reading all the comments here, testing them and still doing some research online. :)

Comment: @yi_H = Why do you have to pollute the global namespace? You can declare your own namespaces in PHP. - I do agree with sepearate functions for each field name being useless.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with NS, i guess if it is possible at all the syntax will be really ugly. and the whole concept of using variables is still terrible, wouldn't ever use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fields($i) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $resultado=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_num_rows($resultado);
    if($row != 0) {
        echo ($row['$fields($i)']);
    } else {
        echo (" No ".$fields($i)." inserted!");
    }
}
for ($i=0; $i<15; $i++) {
    fields($i);
}
```

That function must be out and `$fields` is an array, i hope it works.

Comment: Hey thank you! But unfortunatelly this structure didn't work either. As yi_H says, a function's name can't be based on a variable.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Like what is the end result supposed to do? Are you just trying to check if a field in a row is filled in? To me it just looks like you're complicating your life more than you need to.

EDIT:

Here's how I would do it. Put this in your connect.php:

```
$user = array();
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    $user[$key] = $value;
}
```

With that, you should be able to access any of the users fields by going $user['id'] or $user['password'] provided connect.php is included.

I hope this was helpful.

EDIT 2:

Even simpler:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
$user = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

Comment: Hehe I probably am! What I'm trying to get is an easy way to generate functions that will allow me to query and print all the details of an specific user. So if I need to print their name somewhere or their email or anything, I will just call the function for that field.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting option. But I can't make it work. I've put it right bellow the `include` for my connect.php, and then called it as `<?php echo $user['email']; ?>` and I get this error: `Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\localhost\htdocs\icam\admin\dashboard_admin.php on line 1`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure about the overall approach, but just for fun.... you can use [**variable variables**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to trigger [**anonymous functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) like this:

```
<?php
$fields = array('id', 'username' ...
foreach($fields as $index => $one_field) {
    $$one_field = function() use ($one_field, $index) { ... };
}
```

Note the use of `use`, so I can access the instances of `$one_field` and `$index` that were current when each `$$one_field` was created in the function... creating a true closure.

Now you can access one of these functions like `$username()`

[**Here's a quick illustrative example.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tBegmk)

Answer (score 0):

I know its old, but still, this Works...

```
function test_one(){
print "one";
}
function test_two(){
print "two";
}
$var = "test_two";
$var();
```

Answer (score -4):

You could just use php's [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite), and write the function to file as you would normally. ie `fwrite($handle,'<?php function '.$function_name.' { //function contents here } ?>');` I wouldn't recommend this, but it's doable.

Comment: Tried to clarify a bit better what I meant. You can just directly output the text needed to define a function, and dynamically add the function names you have stored.

Comment: Thankyou @Dschultz. Why is it that you don't recommend the fwrite method?

Comment: In general I wouldn't recommend dynamically writing functions to a file from a db unless you know exactly what you're pulling.

Comment: this is called automatic code generation. It gives an answer to the OP's question, the problem is: the OP has the wrong question :)